# How can I enable AWS VPC Flow logs by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

In the AWS account, if a new VPC is created , I need that VPC flow logs should get enabled (created) automatically. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use EventBridge to automate response to events, currently, VPC is not integrated with EventBridge so you could:

1. Monitor CloudTrail events, particuarly the CreateVPC action as [described in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html).
2. Add an AWS Lambda Function [(AWS docs reference)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail-example.html) that triggers based on the event
3. Modify your function to create the flow log using the SDK (python example [on the AWS docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_flow_logs))